# Searching function using PHP & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

If I enter one value, the system will function properly. The problem is, when I enter more than one value, the system does not display any output. I need the user can enter the data in bulk and separated by a space. Is there any problem with my code?

```
$studid = clean($_POST['studid']);
$studid2 = $studid; 
$studid3 =explode(' ',$studid2);
require("php/conn.php");

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,studid,name from student where studid in('". implode(',', $studid3)."') group by studid,name");

echo"
<table>
<thead><tr><th>NAME</th><th>IC NUMBER</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONE NUMBER</th><th>SOURCE</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) 
{

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
   { 
    echo"
    <tr>
    <td>".$row['nama']."</td>
    <td>".$row['nokp']."</td>
    <td>".$row['alamat2']."</td>
    <td>".$row['notel2']."</td>
    <td>".$row['info']."</td>
    </tr>";
   }

   echo "</tbody></table></div>"; 
}
```

Comment: any error you get... you can simply try with by Echo your query and check wat you get.

Comment: if I enter one value, the system will function properly. output will be displayed..  example input : s123456 but If i enter more than 1 value.. output will not be displayed. example input: s123456 s321 1111 2222

Comment: print your query and check value that you get `echo "SELECT id,studid,name from student where studid in(". implode(',', $studid3).") group by studid,name"`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: if input is s123456, SELECT id,studid,name from student where studid in('s123456') group by studid,name

Comment: if input are s123456 s321321 111 222, it's blank

Comment: Think about it... what will your SQL syntax look like with multiple values? `WHERE IN ('foo,bar,baz')` – probably not what you need. You need `WHERE IN ('foo','bar','baz')`.

Comment: yes I know the problem is there. but i don't know how to add the apostrophe

Comment: Ok, well, think it through. This is a site for programmers, we expect the audience to be able to figure out task of this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
$studid4 = "'" . implode("','", $studid3) . "'";
```

Comment: Would you add an introductory paragraph to say what is happening here? What does the glue of three characters do? We discourage code-only answers, since we don't think they are particularly explanatory on their own.